# Modify file's lastModified/lastAccessed/created date in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, fileapi, qfile

I have an application that copies some files, but during the copy procedure, the last modified, etc dates are changed to the current date & time. On a few forums, I see it is suggested to use the [SETFILETIME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-setfiletime?redirectedfrom=MSDN) call from the `fileapi.h` as specified here on [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-setfiletime?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

However, a quick search shows these functions are available here in [QFileDevice](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledevice.html) where one can use the [setFileTime](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledevice.html#setFileTime) function with the following [FileTime](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledevice.html#FileTime-enum) enum. Note, [QFile](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html) or [QFileInfo](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfileinfo.html) does not allow modifying these dates & times, only reading these dates & times.

> QFileDevice::FileAccessTime   0   When the file was most recently accessed
>   (e.g. read or written to). QFileDevice::FileBirthTime 1   When the file
>   was created (may not be not supported on UNIX).
>   QFileDevice::FileMetadataChangeTime   2   When the file's metadata was
>   last changed. QFileDevice::FileModificationTime   3   When the file was
>   most recently modified.

How can I get a instance of this `QFileDevice` from say a `QFileInfo` object or even a `QFile` object (in this case, `QFile` inherits from `QFileDevice` - will a e.g. static_cast<>() help?

ALternatively, should I rather use the Windows `FileAPI.h` - how can I do this from say some file location and a `QDateTime` to modify the `created` or `lastModified` time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I must admit that I noticed [**QFile::setFileTime()**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledevice.html#setFileTime) the first time due to OPs question. (I never had the necessity to tweak the time stamps of any file written by my S/W.) Out of curiosity, I tried to puzzle this out.

That's what I got:

```
// Qt header:
#include <QtCore>

// main application
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  auto showTimeStamps = [](const QFile &file) {
    qDebug() << "File time stamps of" << file.fileName();
    QFileInfo fileInfo(file);
    qDebug() << "birthTime()   :" << fileInfo.birthTime();
    qDebug() << "lastModified():" << fileInfo.lastModified();
    qDebug() << "lastAccessed():" << fileInfo.lastRead();
  };

  qDebug() << "Qt Version:" << QT_VERSION_STR;
  { QFile file("test.txt");
    // create test file
    qDebug() << "Write test.txt...";
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text)) {
      qDebug() << "Failed to create test.txt!";
      return 1;
    }
    if (file.write("Test.\n") < 0) {
      qDebug() << "Failed to write to test.txt!";
      return 1;
    }
    file.close();
    qDebug() << "Done.";
    // check file time stamps initially
    showTimeStamps(file);
    // manipulate file time stamps
    const QDateTime timeStamp(QDate(1970, 5, 1), QTime(6, 0));
    qDebug() << "Modify time stamp of creation of test.txt:";
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::Append | QIODevice::Text)) {
      qDebug() << "Failed to open test.txt!";
      return 1;
    }
    if (!file.setFileTime(timeStamp, QFileDevice::FileBirthTime)) {
      qDebug() << "Failed to modify create time!";
      return 1;
    }
    file.close();
    showTimeStamps(file);
    qDebug() << "Modify time stamp of last modification of test.txt:";
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::Append | QIODevice::Text)) {
      qDebug() << "Failed to open test.txt!";
      return 1;
    }
    if (!file.setFileTime(timeStamp, QFileDevice::FileModificationTime)) {
      qDebug() << "Failed to modify last modified time!";
      return 1;
    }
    file.close();
    showTimeStamps(file);
    qDebug() << "Modify time stamp of last access of test.txt:";
    file.setFileTime(timeStamp, QFileDevice::FileAccessTime);
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::Append | QIODevice::Text)) {
      qDebug() << "Failed to open test.txt!";
      return 1;
    }
    if (!file.setFileTime(timeStamp, QFileDevice::FileAccessTime)) {
      qDebug() << "Failed to modify last access time!";
      return 1;
    }
    file.close();
    showTimeStamps(file);
  }
  // bail out to enable check in File Explorer afterwards
  return 0;
  // delete test file
  { qDebug() << "Delete test.txt...";
    if (!QFile::remove("test.txt")) {
      qDebug() << "Failed to delete test.txt!";
      return 1;
    }
    qDebug() << "Done.";
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Qt Version: 5.13.0
Write test.txt...
Done.
File time stamps of "test.txt"
birthTime()   : QDateTime(2020-06-18 08:42:09.983 Mitteleuropõische Sommerzeit Qt::LocalTime)
lastModified(): QDateTime(2020-06-18 08:42:09.984 Mitteleuropõische Sommerzeit Qt::LocalTime)
lastAccessed(): QDateTime(2020-06-18 08:42:09.983 Mitteleuropõische Sommerzeit Qt::LocalTime)
Modify time stamp of creation of test.txt:
File time stamps of "test.txt"
birthTime()   : QDateTime(1970-05-01 06:00:00.000 Mitteleuropõische Sommerzeit Qt::LocalTime)
lastModified(): QDateTime(2020-06-18 08:42:09.984 Mitteleuropõische Sommerzeit Qt::LocalTime)
lastAccessed(): QDateTime(2020-06-18 08:42:09.983 Mitteleuropõische Sommerzeit Qt::LocalTime)
Modify time stamp of last modification of test.txt:
File time stamps of "test.txt"
birthTime()   : QDateTime(1970-05-01 06:00:00.000 Mitteleuropõische Sommerzeit Qt::LocalTime)
lastModified(): QDateTime(1970-05-01 06:00:00.000 Mitteleuropõische Sommerzeit Qt::LocalTime)
lastAccessed(): QDateTime(2020-06-18 08:42:09.983 Mitteleuropõische Sommerzeit Qt::LocalTime)
Modify time stamp of last access of test.txt:
File time stamps of "test.txt"
birthTime()   : QDateTime(1970-05-01 06:00:00.000 Mitteleuropõische Sommerzeit Qt::LocalTime)
lastModified(): QDateTime(1970-05-01 06:00:00.000 Mitteleuropõische Sommerzeit Qt::LocalTime)
lastAccessed(): QDateTime(1970-05-01 06:00:00.000 Mitteleuropõische Sommerzeit Qt::LocalTime)
```

Afterwards I verified the time stamps in the Windows File Explorer:

[image: snapshot of File Properties for test.txt]

So, I wonder about the claim of OP

> Note, QFile or QFileInfo does not allow modifying these dates & times, only reading these dates & times.

I had expected that's the actual intention of [**QFile::setFileTime()**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledevice.html#setFileTime), and it seems to work properly on my side.

Comment: thank you for the example, it seems I needed some sleep as the simple property of inheritance seemed to have slipped my mind (somehow) i.e. it didn't occur to me at the time that these functions should be available in inherited classes...need...coffee. Thank you in any case!